# Regex for the following for removing first set of brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to strip out the `"( ( listen) LEE-mər)"` in the following text in javascript, including outer brackets. The content within the outer brackets dynamically changes. I also don't want to strip the next set of brackets `(ghosts or spirits)`

> Here is what I found on Wikipedia: Lemurs ( ( listen) LEE-mər) are a clade of strepsirrhine primates endemic to the island of Madagascar. The word lemur derives from the word lemures (ghosts or spirits) from Roman mythology and was first used to describe a slender loris due to its nocturnal habits and slow pace, but was later applied to the primates on Madagascar."

I got as far as

```
/\((.*?\()*/g
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible to do in regex?

Comment: So how do you detect what to remove? It starts with two brackets? Or are the first brackets in the text

Comment: Try [`s.replace(/\([^()]+\([^()]+\)[^()]+\)/g, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/58Byxb/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex :

```
/\(([^)]*)\)[^)]*\)/
```

To retrieve only what you want :

```
var text = "Here...";
var response = text.match(/\(([^)]*)\)[^)]*\)/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regular expression to match "`( ( listen) LEE-mər)`" and remove it from the text:

```
\(\s*(?=\(\s*listen).+?\).+?\)
```

This does not match `(ghosts or spirits)`.

You can test it on this [link](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5C(%5Cs*(%3F%3D%5C(%5Cs*listen).%2B%3F%5C).%2B%3F%5C)&test_string=Here%20is%20what%20I%20found%20on%20Wikipedia%3A%20Lemurs%20(%20(%20listen)%20LEE-m%C9%99r)%20are%20a%20clade%20of%20strepsirrhine%20primates%20endemic%20to%20the%20island%20of%20Madagascar.%20The%20word%20lemur%20derives%20from%20the%20word%20lemures%20(ghosts%20or%20spirits)%20from%20Roman%20mythology%20and%20was%20first%20used%20to%20describe%20a%20slender%20loris%20due%20to%20its%20nocturnal%20habits%20and%20slow%20pace%2C%20but%20was%20later%20applied%20to%20the%20primates%20on%20Madagascar.%22&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Here is an example in Javascript:

```js
const str = "Here is what I found on Wikipedia: Lemurs ( ( listen) LEE-mər) are a clade of strepsirrhine primates endemic to the island of Madagascar. The word lemur derives from the word lemures (ghosts or spirits) from Roman mythology and was first used to describe a slender loris due to its nocturnal habits and slow pace, but was later applied to the primates on Madagascar.";
const transformed = str.replace(/\(\s*(?=\(\s*listen).+?\).+?\)/g, "");
document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = str;
document.getElementById("transformed").innerHTML = transformed;
```

```html
<div id="str"></div>
<br />
<div id="transformed"></div>
```

### Regex explanation

The regex looks first for a left round bracket followed by zero or more spaces:

```
\(\s*
```

which is followed by "listen" in brackets (using positive lookahead):

```
(?=\(\s*listen)
```

This is then followed by any non greedy number of characters followed by a bracket two times:

```
.+?\).+?\)
```

### Regex optimisation

You could optimize the original regex with this one:

```
\(\s*(?=\(\s*listen)(.+?\)){2}
```